# Has anyone gotten Powerlevel9k Theming to look good on the *new* Windows Terminal/WSL?

Tags: terminal, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh, windows-terminal

I've been trying to use WSL and the new Windows Terminal and wanted to make it look nice.

I'm somewhat new to zsh and shell theming though I've multiple pieces of documentation which seemed pretty straight forward and I'm still having issues making things look nice.

1.) Segment separating Arrows appear just a tad off
2.) Black backgrounds appear transparent.

When I read online, I only see examples of those who use zsh and powerlevel9k on Macs or linux, or some alternative terminal for Windows, but have yet to see an example for the New Windows Terminal. Has anyone tried this? Are there bugs with the Windows Terminal preventing themes from rendering correctly, or is it all on me? :D

Also if you've been able to fix any of the above issues for the new Windows Terminal, let me know of course!

Answer (score 4):

Making powerline connections look nice is difficult but there are good alternatives that may look even better.

The easier way to find the best prompt look for your terminal is to switch from Powerlevel9k to Powerlevel10k (it's backward compatible but faster and has extra features), restart zsh and then run configuration wizard. If you are using Oh-My-Zsh, here are the commands to run:

```
git clone https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/powerlevel10k
( cd $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/powerlevel10k && git pull )
sed -e 's/powerlevel9k/powerlevel10k/g' -i ~/.zshrc
exec zsh
```

Once prompt appears, type `p10k configure`. If it doesn't look good, [install the recommended font](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#recommended-meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k).